# Масштабирование изображений android

Tags: android, ui, imageview, android-ui, framelayout

Мне необходимо расположить на экране картинку, а поверх нее еще картинки (и текст). Для этого я использую FrameLayout.
Проблема возникает при изменении разрешения экрана. Картинка, которая лежит поверх основной начинает сдвигаться. Если задать размеры изображений в dp, то картинки не смещаются, но становятся маленькими на некоторых разрешениях экрана.
Как сделать, чтобы все изображения изменялись пропорционально и не смещались?
Ниже приведен пример картинок
[image: 1080x1920, 420dpi]

[image: 800x1280]

[image: Если задать размеры в match_parent или wrap_content]
Серое изображение накладывается на ось.
Ко`

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="13">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView17"
                android:layout_width="700dp"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:minHeight="700dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/background" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView18"
                android:layout_width="79dp"
                android:layout_height="148dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="-266dp"

                android:layout_marginLeft="-265dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:scaleX="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/back1" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

`

Comment: Можете добавить картинки с проблемами? Не могу какой неправильный результат вы получаете. А вообще с FrameLayout вы не получите того, что хотите, скорее всего. Если вы хотите получить точного расположения картинок относительно друг друга нельзя пользоваться dp, нужна своя система координат которую вы будете отображать на текущем экране с текущими настройками. dp не дадут вам такой гибкости

Comment: Проблема изображена на картинках в вопросе. Я хочу, чтобы серое изображение накладывалось на основное (изображение оси) и при смене разрешения оно всегда накладывалось в том же месте. Сейчас я пробую с помощью constraintlayout, но накладываемое изображение все равно смещается

Comment: Неправильный результат - последняя картинка. Желаемый - первая

Answer (score 1):

Вы подгоняете ваши картинки с помощью margin и width/height, указанных в dp. Пункт первый, с margin шансов получить результат 0. На втором скрине видно, что ваши 700dp заняли так много места в ширину, что margin для большой картинки начал "игнорироваться". А margin маленькой нет. Отсюда и смещение. Если использовать AbsoluteLayout и не использовать margin, то должно работать, но с возможными проблемами, связанными с отношением пиксель-dp. Я бы рекомендовал написать свой ViewGroup, который будет исходя из собственных размеров выставлять большую картинку, а из полученных координат большой картинки вычислять положение меньшей.

Создаете класс наследованный от ViewGroup, помещаете в него обе ваши картинки, в методе onLayout рассчитываете положение обеих и отдаете им вызвав их метод layout. Если выложите сами картинки(можно, например, на почту в профиле) может сам попробую что-то такое написать, задачка вроде простая но довольно необычная